# Matcher.find (int start) not working within a region

Tags: java, regex, replace

I am trying to match within a selection in a JTextArea and I am using Matcher.region() to define the boundary of my match:

```
JTextComponent t;

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("string", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(t.getText()).region(t.getSelectionStart(), t.getSelectionEnd());
m.useAnchoringBounds(false);

if(m.find()) {
  System.out.println("Found match from " + m.start() + " to " + m.end());
}
else {
  System.out.println("No match found");
}
```

The above works as expected and it will find the first match within the region - if no match is found then it doesn't find a match.

However, I am trying to loop through the matches within the region (search and replace type function) and if I specify a start position to find() that is within the region then it matches outside of the region:

```
int cPos = m.regionStart();
if (m.find(cPos) || m.find(m.regionStart())) {
  System.out.println("Found match from " + m.start() + " to " + m.end());
  cPos = m.end();
}
else {
  System.out.println("No match found");
}
```

Is this a bug or am I breaking the region if I specify a start position - even if it is contained within the region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28int%29):

`public boolean find(int start)`

> **Resets** this matcher and then [...]

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the obvious :) I assumed it would work the same as find() and not perform a reset, but it works as documented. I have now ended up using a non-region based solution which checks that start() and end() are within my selection.

Comment: I just had to deal with Matcher class these days, and is rather one of the most bad designed official class I ever seen. Tasks that are simple to do reading char by char (for instance, splitting string after special characters or white spaces) becomes hell to do with this class (that also lack significative usage examples).
See this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772860/how-to-create-a-tokenizer-with-the-util-regex-matcher-java
Another thing that you can get only by trial and test is what is region and internal state.